# ¿Cómo usar método en clase hija para identificar objeto?

Tags: clase, herencia, método

Consulto algo que hice y ahora metí la pata y me genero una duda:
Tengo esta clase Super(Publicacion) y una clase hija(Fasiculo).  Si tengo que agregar stock por numero de fasiculo...
Còmo debería  usar llamar desde la clase hija Fasiculo la variable numeroFasiculo?.
Me explico?
publicacion 1 fasiculo 1 stock 3
publicacion 2 fasiculo 1 stock 5

aunque esto es lo que me hice una idea y ahora me confundo, no se si el stock va en la super o en la hija...
en principio, si alguien tiene una forma agil de manejar un método que me mande desde la hija, a la super.  em ayuda mucho.
gracias.
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Publicacion {
    private String nombre;
    private String editorial;
    private float precio;
    private int stock;

```
public Publicacion (String nom, String edi, float pre, int stk) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("FASICULO");
    nombre = nom;
    editorial = edi;
    precio = pre;
    stock = stk;
}

public abstract int getNumeroFasiculo();
public abstract String getAutor();
public abstract int getStockMinimo();
public abstract boolean sosNumeroFasiculo(int a);

public void setStock(int stk) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("FASICULO");
    stock = stock + stk;    
}

public int getStock() {
    return stock;
}   

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
}

import java.util.*;

public class Fasiculo extends Publicacion {
private int numeroFasiculo;
private int stockMinimo;

public Fasiculo (String nombre, String editorial, float precio, int stock, int numFas, int stkMin) {
    super (nombre, editorial, precio, stock);
    numeroFasiculo = numFas;
    stockMinimo = stkMin;
}

public int getNumeroFasiculo() {
    return numeroFasiculo;
}

public int getStockMinimo() {
    return stockMinimo;
}

public boolean sosFasiculo(int n) {
    return (numeroFasiculo == n);
}

@Override
public String getAutor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean sosNumeroFasiculo(int a) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, en tu caso el stock es una funcionalidad propia de Fasiculo. Miralo de la siguiente manera:

Tienes la publicación 1, si le añades el stock sería un stock total de todos los fascículos que es algo totalmente válido, pero no es lo que buscas.

Para el Fasiculo con ID_Publicacion 1(En tu caso no tienes definido uno pero por ejemplo tomemos el nombre y la editorial como identificador único de publicación) y ID_Fasiculo 1(número de fasiculo)  vas a tener un stock propio que corresponde a un valor de 3 unidades. Por lo que ese stock ha de pertenecer y ser gestionado por la clase Fasiculo independientemente de si quieres tener un stock global de todos los fascículos el la clase publicación.

Ahora cuando tengas publicación 2 Fasiculo 1 tu stock de Fasiculo(idPublicacion 2, idFasiculo 1) será de 5. Siendo tu stock global en caso de interesarte Publicación.getStock() = 7 que es la suma de todos sus Fasiculos.

Está sería la manera correcta de abordar tu situación.
En caso de tener un listado de publicaciones y querer saber  el stock concreto de una y luego el de todos sus Fasiculos:

`Publicacion p1 = new Fasiculo("nombrePublicacion", "nombreEditorial", 33, stockFasiculo 4, idFasiculo 1).
List<Publicaciones> publicaciones = new ArrayList<>();
publicaciones.add(p1);`

En este caso anterior p1.getStock devolverá el stock individual correspondiente al Fasiculo 1. Para el stock total tienes que recorrer la lista buscando publicaciones(mismo nombre y misma editorial) y haciendo un sumatorio de sus stock individual.

Coméntame cualquier duda que tengas.
Un saludo.